# C# how to increment variable in constructor - windows service

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, windows-services, webclient

I have a Windows service and I want to change the URL whenever the constructor is called. I am forming the URL in the constructor by concatenating a variable to it and the variable is being incremented (as shown in the code below).

However, the URL is not changing, I am still downloading the same XML file from the URL.

I have tried this:

```
private string Url;
    private string Name = @"D:\test\userko.xml";
    private System.Timers.Timer timer;

    private Downloader xd;
    private static int i;



    public Service1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        while (i < 5000)
        {
            Url = "http://tis-toolbox.appspot.com/api/user/id/" + i + ".xml";
            i++;
            if (i == 4999)
                i = 0;
            break;
        }

        xd = new Downloader(Url, Name);
        timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        timer.Enabled = true;
        timer.Interval = 1000;
        timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(timer_Elapsed);
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        EventLog.WriteEntry("PCTrss reader Service Started.");
        tryDownload();
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        EventLog.WriteEntry("PCTrss reader Service was shutdown.");
    }

    private void timer_Elapsed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tryDownload();
    }

    private void tryDownload()
    {
        try
        {
            timer.Stop();
            xd.DownloadXML();
            EventLog.WriteEntry("PCTrss reader downloaded news at " + xd.LastUpdate + ". XML is in " + Name);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            EventLog.WriteEntry("PCTrss reader Service cannot download feeds " + ex.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            timer.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the Downloader class. It reads and saves an XML file from the URL.

```
class Downloader
{
    public DateTime LastUpdate;
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Downloader(string url, string name) 
    {
        this.Url = url;
        this.Name = name;
    }

    public void DownloadXML()
    {
        if (!Directory.Exists(@"D:\test"))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(@"D:\test");

        LastUpdate = DateTime.Now;



        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        using( Stream stream = client.OpenRead(Url) )
        using( StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream) )
        using( FileStream fs = new FileStream(Name, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
        using( StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs) )
        {
            string s = sr.ReadToEnd();
            sw.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End);
            sw.Write(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: where is the variable `i` declared? is it a field / property of the class? Also, what is the error you're getting?

Comment: i is a global variable. There is no error..but the xml will not download. When I run it without while loop is all ok.But I need change the url.

Comment: i think you need to clarify you question and show us the code for 'Downloader()', and where you define 'Name', what is xd? where are you expecting the xml to end up in?

Comment: The code provided has no sense.... assuming you are initializing the variable i to 0 (and doing < not >), it will never get to 5000 because the break stmt, so why is that code there. Plus the constructor will run only once (when the service is instanciated). When it comes to windows service, usually you don't have a bunch of intances running at the same time, not sure what are you trying to do....

Comment: I edit the post and add the code of downloader.

Comment: i change clause and now download it the same xml.

Comment: Have you try to start to instances of your widnows service at once?

Comment: if i not misunderstood, what you want is count instances of service 1, which it will always be one

Comment: yes I want one service you will download   1.xml and after some time 2.xml ..etc

Answer (score 1):

there are a couple issues:

First, as berXpert noted, the correct clause in the while loop should be `i < 5000`. Second, the entire code should be in the while loop if you want to download 5000 times

```
while (i < 5000)    
{
    Url = "http://tis-toolbox.appspot.com/api/user/id/" + i + ".xml";
    i++;
    xd = new Downloader(Url, Name);
    timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    timer.Enabled = true;
    timer.Interval = 1000;
    timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(timer_Elapsed);
}
```

Also, you don't need the `break` in the `while` loop, it won't be executed more than 5000 times (assuming `i` starts out as 0)

Comment: its wokr but i want to work with downloaded xml and this code is too fast.It download in a moment xml with index 4999

Comment: i add in code System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000); but there is system error Error 1053 the service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to change the while clause to be

```
i < 5000
```

And to have `i` as a shared static property

```
private static int;
```

Comment: such iteration variables as `i` should be declared within the same scope as the iteration itself. Not as a private field of the class and certainly not static